# java.util.MissingResourceException while using ResourceBundle

Tags: java, resources

I write a java JDBC file to access the data from mySQL and I want to hide my password on git. I followed this answer: [How to hide MySQL Connection String- Username and Password on GitHub (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785314/how-to-hide-mysql-connection-string-username-and-password-on-github-java) , but I keep get the error message "java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name...".

I know that this question have been ask many times, but none of the answer solve my problem.

I think It's might because I put the properties file in the wrong direction?

I put the .java file in project/src/

and .properties file in project/src/ (I've also tried put it at project/resource/  and  project/src/resource)

Here's part of my java code:

```
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        ResourceBundle reader = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {           
            reader = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dbconfig.properties");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(reader.getString("db.url"), 
                    reader.getString("db.username"), reader.getString("db.password"));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;        
    }
```

Here's my content of dbconfig.properties:

```
#DB Properties
 db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nerve_game?charactorEncoding=utf-8
 db.username=my_name
 db.password=my_password
```

Thanks.

Comment: It should be "dbconfig", not "dbconfig.properties". The javadoc is your friend. If you read it, you'll also dscover you're using the wrong tool. ResourceBundle is for internationalization, not for reading properties. To read properties, you can just use ... java.util.Properties.

Comment: Thank you. I used java.util.Properies and it totally solve my problem.